# Найти элемент, по части названия класса

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется контейнер, который при перезагрузке страницы может изменять часть названия класса.
Он может быть .actionsWrapper-58 или .actionsWrapper-90.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне находить эти классы, если они имеют одно, или другое название? В последующем, я вставляю в них контент.

```
const classString = '.actionsWrapper-58'

const articleDiv = document.querySelector(classString)
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('[class*="actionsWrapper-"]')`

Answer (score -1):

Например так:

```js
$('.actionsWrapper*').each(function(){
  $('body').append($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=".actionsWrapper-58">
  content 58
</div>
<div class=".actionsWrapper-70">
  content 70
</div>
<div class=".actionsWrapper-81">
  content 81
</div>
<div class=".actionsWrapper-90">
  content 90
</div>
```

Comment: Вы вообще код проверяли?

Comment: @ΝNL993        да, он работает.

Comment: Уберите весь ваш jQuery и посмотрите, будут ли различия.